# Compare each array string with int

Tags: java, string, arraylist, int

Hello if i want to compare this string:

```
private String str;

public String str() {
    return str;
}

public void str(String str) {
    this.str = str;
}
```

That contain an variable of int:

```
str = StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString(var);
```

Where var is an array list

```
List<Integer> var = new ArrayList<>();
```

On this list insert this resul:

```
for (int hour=0; hour<24; hour++) {
if (my conditions is ok) {          
            var.add(hour);}
```

And contain an example var=[3,10,18] and consequently str = [3,10,18], if i want compare in my method this string with a 0 - 23 number hour and return 1 if equals each one or 0.

```
@Override
public Map<String, Object> my() {
    List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int hour=0; hour<23; hour++) {
        if (.......... conditions TO DO){       
            test.add(1);
        }
        else {
            test.add(0);
        }

    }  }
```

An example in this case test result i want to done:

test=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: I would start off  by renaming both your methods. Having methods with the same names as your fields is bad enough - having one method that *returns* the value of the field and another method that assigns a *new* value to the field, both called the same thing, is a really bad idea. Next, it's not clear what that first code has to do with anything else in the question. Please provide a [mcve] and make your question as clear as possible.

Comment: It's not big deal to compare string representation of integer to some string. More interesting is the question of "why do you need to compare like that"? I'd refactor that in a heartbeat: you got your numeric values right there, wouldn't it be easier to fill a list using them as indexes, not comparing each with all possible permutations?

Comment: Also, what's with return values? Where is the `Map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `contains(Object o)` method of `java.util.List` to check if the iterated `int hour` is contained in `List<Integer> var`:

```
if (var.contains(hour)){
```

Note that the `hour` is not an `Object` but a primitive `int`. Autoboxing does the automatic conversion to `Integer`.

The method would be so :

```
@Override
public Map<String, Object> my() {
    List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int hour=0; hour<23; hour++) {
        if (var.contains(hour)){       
            test.add(1);
        }
        else {
            test.add(0);
        }

    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution